# Dagger 2 - Injected Dependency is always null

Tags: android, dagger-2

Hello so I've been going crazy trying to figure out what I haven't configured properly to get a non null dependency when injecting into a class.  Below is my current code

```
public interface DaggerGraph {

    void inject(SplashActivity splashActivity);
}
```

DaggerGraph to provide interface for injecting

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {MainModule.class})
public interface DaggerComponent extends DaggerGraph {

    final class Initializer {
        private Initializer() {
        }

        public static DaggerComponent init(Application app) {
            return DaggerDaggerComponent.builder()
                .mainModule(new MainModule(app))
                .build();
        }
    }
}
```

The Dagger component

```
@Module
public class MainModule {

    private final Application app;

    public MainModule(Application app) {
        this.app = app;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Application provideApplication() {
        return app;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Resources provideResources() {
        return app.getResources();
    }
}
```

The Main Module

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static DaggerComponent daggerComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        daggerComponent = DaggerComponent.Initializer.init(this);
    }

    public static DaggerComponent component() {
        return daggerComponent;
    }

}
```

Application

```
public class SplashActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Inject
    Resources resources;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        App.component().inject(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Timber.d(Boolean.toString(resources == null)); //Always true
    }
}
```

In this activity Resources is ALWAYS null and its driving me crazy.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Peculiar. The only thing that looks out of place to me is `DaggerGraph` since I never saw extending an interface for injections before. I would try removing the `DaggerGraph` interface and just using `DaggerComponent` and see if that works. And since this is dagger 2, there is always the option to just look at the generated source code or debug your way through ;)

Comment: I just solved it...and I'm an idiot.  I used AS autocomplete for the onCreate method and it autocompleted the wrong method... DOH

Comment: `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {` yep that's totally not the `protected` version of `onCreate()`.

Comment: @SemaphoreMetaphor please convert your comment to an answer.